# Button Click event doesn't trigger shortly after pressing keys on keyboard (C# Windows Forms Application)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working on some Windows Form Application using Microsoft Visual C# 2010.
I have noticed, that  shortly (fraction of a second) after pressing keys on keyboard, mouse click on a button (`System.Windows.Forms.Button`) doesn't trigger the `Click` event.

I know I can work this around using `MouseUp` event, which works perfectly fine, still i'd like to stick to the `Click` event for some reasons.

Does anyone know this issue? Does it vary depending on .NET Framework or Windows version? I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 version 10.0.40219.1 Sp1Rel and Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.5.51209 SP1Rel. on Windows 7 Home Premium SP1.

I didn't post any code, because i don't think it's the culprit. I tested the problem on a freshly created Windows Form with 1 button with assigned `Click` event handler and it happened too.

Comment: Can you clarify the steps to reproduce?  Is it 1) Create a Winform with a single button 2) run it 3) move my mouse over the button 4) Press the "A" key 5) wait 150ms 6) click button, the result is no click event?  Did I get that right?

Comment: Quick guess (and it's definitely a guess).  Perhaps it has to do with some weird focusing problem.  You might try printline debugging with focus events as well.

Comment: @MobyDisk  I meant the opposite, the event fails to trigger if clicked too fast after typing. So skip the "5) wait 150ms" and repeat a couple of times to make sure you were fast enough.

Comment: Do you have other events on this button?

Comment: @Pabinator yes and no. Tested together with `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` both triggered everytime even if `Click` failed.

Comment: I will say if the 'Click' event doesn't fire and it is the only event on that button then it may be related to heavy processing.  Try using the BackgroundWorker on the heavy processing method so the button event can work.

Comment: This would happen if you click the mouse while the key is down and then let go of the key before releasing the mouse button.  The ButtonBase.OnKeyUp() method resets the "mouse is down" flag, something it needs to do because a button can be operated by both the mouse and the keyboard.  Nobody ever notices this because it doesn't make sense to use the keyboard when the button has the focus, other than pressing the Space key.

Comment: @HansPassant that's a very interesting answer.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for clarifying the problem, it works exactly how you said. About making sense, the focus wasn't on the button until the mouse button was pressed down.